# direct parent of a element inside a th is the row?

Tags: html, css

why absolute element inside  th have the parent set to the row instead of the th?
how can make absolute positioned child element to position relative to th and not the row

http://jsfiddle.net/tH7TK/

Comment: Hi, please check this link about [css positioning](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html) and this [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/tH7TK/3/), may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's relative to the `th`, just as it you think it should be, and not to the `tr`. Take a look at the modified fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tH7TK/1.

Comment: An element with `position: absolute` is relative to the document if none of the it's ancestors has a `position` other than `static`.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tH7TK/2/)*

```
th *{
 
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;

}
```

Comment: From Arturo's question and from what I understood from his code, Arturo wants whatever element is targeted by `th *` to be positioned relative to the `th`. And what he's done achieves just that, he's just not seeing it. Using `position: relative` on `th *` makes it's positioning (using top, left, etc) relative to it's default position - that's not what he wants, I believe.